# Rails 4, Heroku, Zurb Foundation 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I am developing a site using Foundation 5 that I'm hosting on Heroku. Yesterday all the Foundation widgets that are dependent on javascript stopped working on Heroku. In my case this means all my modals and my orbit slider. It still works flawlessly on my local machine.

I'm always precompiling my assets (rake assets:precompile) and commiting the compiled version before pushing to Heroku with git.

I've tried down and upgrading between Foundation versions 5.0.2.0 and 5.0.3.1 and a few other things but I'm just stumped on where to even start. I'm not too good with javascript debuggning either.

```
Production.rb
  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this).
  config.serve_static_assets = true

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs.
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets.
  config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

-

```
application.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.touchcarousel-1.2.min
//= require foundation
//= require jquery.ui.button
//= require jquery.tap.min
//= require modernizr

//= require jquery-fileupload/basic
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });

//$('#TjuvkikModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
//$('#ExempelobjektModal').foundation('reveal', 'open');
```

Comment: i see you added jquery.turbolinks, but no turbolinks. try removing the jquery.turbolinks include, it might mess up your jquery

Comment: You're right - I removed Turbolinks so it wouldn't be in the way, but I missed that one. Thanks - but still not working on Heroku.

Comment: I don't see a `require_self` in `application.js`. Is `$(document).foundation();` ever getting called?

Comment: Ben I started on my answer below before I saw your comment. This totally makes sense (and makes me an idiot). Going to test it tonight and then I'll get back to you!

Comment: Interesting however that it worked on my local machine - do you know why?

Comment: @BenTaitelbaum It actually seems "require_self" is only needed in the application.CSS. application.JS itself is included in "require_tree". I tested it to make sure. But thank you anyhow for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this problem. It seems that Foundation wasn't initialized by:

```
$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });
```

in my application.js (see above). When i pasted it into the end of applicaton.html as a script tag like so:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<script type="text/javascript">$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });</script>
</div>
```

it suddenly started working. This seems crazy to me. The script tag is the very next line of code that gets read after application.js. Why would this make any difference? And only on Heroku? If anyone knows the answer please comment and shed some light!